# Approximate data to $y=a*e^{b*x}$ using method of least squares

Tags: approximation, interpolation

I have some data. For example

```
x 1.2 2.8 4.3
y 7.5 16.1 38.9
```

I wonder how to find $a$ and $b$ of function $y=a*e^{bx}$ that approximates the data with method of least squares.

Comment: Start taking logarithms to have a linear regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the logarithm of both sides:
$$\ln y = \ln a + bx$$

And now use linear regression to find $a$ and $b$.